# Does locking a row in MySQL/InnoDB always lock all associated index records as well?

Tags: mysql, locking, innodb

When a row in MySQL/InnoDB is locked (whether implicitly due to the isolation level of a transaction, or explicitly using `SELECT * ... FOR UPDATE` or ``... LOCK IN SHARE MODE`):

Does this lock also apply to all index records associated with the row, or will only the index record used to access the lock by the locking statement itself be locked?

As an example, assume that there exists a table with columns `x`, `y`, and `z`, where `x` and `y` are indexed.

Will the statement `SELECT * FROM Table WHERE x = foo`, which returns one record with `(x = foo, y = bar, z = c)` also make all statements like `SELECT * FROM Table WHERE y = bar` wait on the lock, or can these still be executed concurrently (assuming that they will not attempt to modify the locked row itself, of course)?

**Update:** Please note that the question is *not* about index record or gap locks in general. It is about the specific case of a locking read via scanning index `x`, and whether or not that will make queries scanning over `y` wait.

Comment: Also, https://www.percona.com/blog/2012/03/27/innodbs-gap-locks/

Comment: @Drew I know how index record and gap locking works. This question is specifically about the indexes which are _not_ scanned by the locking query.

Comment: Such as ones in another database?

Comment: No, the ones on the same table which are not referenced in the SELECT. In my example that would be the index on ``y``.

Answer (score -1):

tl;dr: No.

When you use MySQL/InnoDB and you `SELECT *... FOR UPDATE`, the rows that are locked are [**only** the rows you selected](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/internal-locking.html#idm139721065597712).

In your case - if you have a `SELECT * FROM Table WHERE x = foo FOR UPDATE`, only the rows that matches the `WHERE x = foo` are locked (if you have some other rows that are `y = bar AND x != foo` these rows **will not** be locked.

Comment: In my observations, even skipped rows are locked in InnoDB, which is also consistent with the documentation: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-locks-set.html

Comment: See discussions of "gap locking".

Comment: This is not true. There's gap lock.